# OnClick on generated Textblock

Tags: windows-phone-7

Howdy,
I'm generating a bunch of Textblocks in a StackPanel. I would love to open another page when clicking on one Textbox:

sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Click me, I wanna open new content" });

How could I do that, it's probably something with "triggers" but I couldn't find anything on the web :-/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) to add a gesture listener for the `Tap` event.

Alternatively you could use a [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as this contains a `Click` event.

**Edit:**
Example of using HyperlinkButton:

```
var sp = new StackPanel();

var hlb = new HyperlinkButton {Content = "click me"};
hlb.Click += hlb_Click;

sp.Children.Add(hlb);

ContentPanel.Children.Add(sp);


private void hlb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with the hyperlinkbutton:

sp.Children.Add(new HyperlinkButton { Content = "Click me pleeease",  NavigateUri = "/MyTestView.xaml" }); but the VS says that it cannot convert String to a URI .. I tried to cast it with (uri) but it isn't working either.

Comment: @theXs Use the click event to handle the navigation. `NavigateUri` doesn't work with realtive URIs

Comment: I can only define the clickmode event in the definition of the hyperlinkbutton.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also need two IDs to navigate to the next page, the best way would be to store those two IDs in the name of the button and split them up in the onClick Method, right?

Comment: @theXs the `Tag` property might be more appropriate than making them part of the name. `(sender as FrameworkElement).Tag`

Comment: Ok, cool thanks! Already found that Tag element tho - but not how I could use it... Thanks a lot, ur great!

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextBlock.ManipulationStarted` event to detect a touch on it.